# How can I specify tolerance for floating point operation in CGAL library?

Tags: floating-point, precision, computational-geometry, cgal

Is there a way to specify tolerance for CGAL geometry operations? I use `exact_predicates_inexact_constructions` kernel for computational speed. However sometimes operations such as determining a point lies within a polygon or not seems to provide outcomes that are contaminated by inaccuracy of the floating point representation. I was wondering if there is a way of providing tolerance for such decisions with CGAL package